# Laravel Policy not injecting current user

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, ioc-container

I'm trying to bind a policy for a user that checks if he has a record in another table and a flag set to true. However, the policy I'm using doesn't inject the current user.

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
/**
 * The policy mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $policies = [
    \App\Http\Models\User::class => \App\Policies\UserPolicy::class,
];
```

**App\Policies\UserPolicy**

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Http\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function view(User $user)
    {
        return true;
        // currently just debug value
    }
}
```

In the laravel docs it's stated as:

> All policies are resolved via the Laravel service container, meaning you may type-hint any needed dependencies in the policy's constructor and they will be automatically injected.

When using `auth()->user()->can('view')` - in a controller that **depends** on the records of the table I'll check - always returns false, no matter what. The only way to get it working is by calling
`auth()->user()->can('view', auth()->user())` or `$this->authorize('view', auth()->user())`

What am I missing to get the first method to work?

**EDIT:** It doesn't matter if I typehint the user in the method itself or in the constructor as it seems to be ignored.

Comment: I believe you have to update the model you want to authenticate. By default the model is App\User and not App\Models\User. Maybe that will work. I'm not sure... Just a guess

Comment: No, I moved my structure as I don't like the Models to be "just" in the app directory

Comment: Yeah, sure. I do that same